# Adding a zero before values in an Excel spreadsheet column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

While trying to fill in social security numbers into Excel 2007, my dad found out that he couldn't make the numbers start with a zero (`0`).

Example: `0123456789` is turned into `123456789`

What do I need to do in order for the leading zeros to stay as-is entered and not disappear?

Comment: Can you enlighten me? Not being an American, I'm not sure what kinds of things you do with Social Security Numbers, but I wouldn't expect any *calculation* is involved. Couldn't you enter them as text and keep the leading 0, by prefixing a quote character?

Comment: Excel's default number format takes away the 0, regardless of what you're doing with it. And yes a ' would probably solve it, but I wasn't aware of it before he encountered the issue and it's -1 for usability...

Comment: Yes, it would be a pain entering those ' characters if there's a lot of data entry.

Comment: Changing the cell data type to text doesnt change anything, Excel still automatically drops the leading zero. I wonder why this is, obviously a fault in the program. What if the name of your business starts with a zero, this would be highly annoying to change custom with allt those '0's every time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the numbers you're inserting all have a common length, you can set a custom format on them:

[image]

So if you wanted 123456789 to turn into 0123456789, you'd use the format `0000000000`.

Comment: And not a freehand circle in sight!

Comment: The question super easy to answer, but I can imagine more people encountering this issue!

Comment: Freehand circles added upon request

Comment: Hmmm, too bad the ugliest-freehand-joke made it to Super User too...

Comment: Like @dkusleika pointed out in a comment at Joril's answer at http://superuser.com/questions/88870/how-do-you-add-zero-before-values-in-excel-document/88898#88898 -- if things are not meant for calculations (like social security numbers) then one should probably not format as a number either?

Comment: It's a custom format which just adds leading zeros. I don't think he will be doing calculations on SSNs, but Joril's answer will work as well.

Comment: The value remains a number internally - it only displays it with your formatting (and also when copy-pasting to other apps). In fact, if you want to use the value including zeros in a formula (such as for text concatenation), you'll need to use the formula TEXT(A1, "000000000") to convert it to text first.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to type a quotation mark (') and then the number.. This way the number is treated as a string, so the leading zeros are kept. (The quote won't be displayed)

Comment: This makes calculations harder, I guess?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing calculations on SSNs, I think is the point.  Credit card #s, SSNs, and other ID #s should be entered as text because that's what they are.  IMHO of course.

Comment: I missed that part of the question. I think @dkusleika is right!

Comment: and if you need to do calculations on SSNs (or any other text field) you can always run it through a converter to get a number from the real data.

Answer (score 4):

Excel has special formatting for Social Security Numbers.

1. Select the cells where you want to type the SSN's
2. Right click and choose "Format Cells"
3. On the "Number" tab, choose "Special" (toward the bottom of the list)
4. On the right you'll see "Social Security Number". Select it and click "OK"

When you type the SSN's in those cells, they will take leading zeros.

Comment: +1 The only answer that actually addresses the specific question!

Answer (score 2):

You can always format the column as 'Text' **before** entering the values.
That way Excel does not try to guess if it is a number or not and will keep the leading zeros.

That saves the hassle of entering ' before entering the number.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992588/3664960, I think this is the fastest and easiest:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0000")
```

However the TEXT function is able to do other fancy stuff like date formating, aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I found [the solution on a forum:](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=297466)

> Your numbers are probably stores as
>   numbers, if you still want them stored
>   as numbers you could use custom number
>   formatting.
>
> Select Format -> Cell -> Number ->
>   Custom
>
> Enter this format: 00000000000
>
> This makes your number display with 11
>   digits and leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

We can't ignore zero as you know how it is important to us. You can add zero before any number by performing the following steps:

1. Open the **MS Excel worksheet**.
2. Write the number in the cell before you want to add zero.
3. Right click the mouse in the cell, select Format Cells... option. **Format Cells** window will be displayed.
4. Select the Numbers tab from the window then click **Custom option** from the left **Category**: section.
5. Select 0 option from the Type section.
6. Type the no. of zeroes as many as your number contains digit. For example, your number is **12345**, so now you need to enter five zeros after the selected 0 in the type section i.e. **000000**.
7. Click OK. The number of zeros entered by you will be converted to digits and the result would be 012345