# Add 0's to values in column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you add zero before values in excel document?](https://superuser.com/questions/88870/how-do-you-add-zero-before-values-in-excel-document)

I am trying to edit product codes in Excel so that each product code is exactly 8 digits in length.

Currently the product codes are different lengths, for example:

```
12
1222
213212
32
3231
3213131
```

The above codes *should* read as follows:

```
00000012
00001222
00213212
00000032
00003231
03213131
```

As you can see all product codes are now 8 digits in length, any product codes that were less than 8 have had the correct number of 0's prepended to them.

Any help with an Excel formula that would magically do this for me would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the cells with a custom format to always use at least eight digits, so the format would be:

```
00000000
```

The Microsoft article [Using a custom number format to display leading zeros](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/81518) provides more information that you might find useful.

The same method works in LibreOffice.