# How to start a number with zero in Excel CSV format

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a zero before values in an Excel spreadsheet column?](https://superuser.com/questions/88870/adding-a-zero-before-values-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-column)

I'm trying to start a number with zero in Excel's CSV format, but I'm not able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are doing this with excel, you have to format this column or cell where you want to have leading zeros as text-format or with a custom format like "0000.00".

Another way would be entering your values like this `'001005`

Answer (score 2):

You should edit your question to provide an example of how your CSV file might look.

I think you mean your CSV file looks something like this:

```
01,022,100,04
```

and you want Excel to show this:

```
[  01][  022][  100][  04]
```

but Excel displays this as:

```
[  1][  22][  100][  4]
```

If this describes your problem, then try adding a single-quote-mark (apostrophe) before the number in your CSV file to indicate text rather than numeric like this: (as suggested by Jook)

```
'01,'022,'100,'04
```

which should work, but this could very much depend on your version of Excel.

If that doesn't work, try using double quotes like this:

```
"01","022","100","04"  
-or-  
"'01","'022","'100","'04"
```